# Nested objects in Dapper Query parameter

Tags: c#, dapper

I have an object like the following and I would like to send it as a parameter for a Dapper query.

```
var person = new {
    Name = "John",
    Company = new {
        Name = "ACME"
    }
};

var res = connection.Query("select concat(@Name, @Company_Name) as concatted", person);
```

My problem is that the `@Company_Name` does not get used. I tried replacing it with `@Company.Name`, but that gave an AggregateException, with a SystemNotSupportedException: `The member Company of type ..... cannot be used as a parameter value`.

What is the correct way to use the nested object of the passed param object inside the query?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to match the query parameter names in your param object:

```
 var res = conn.Query("select concat(@Name, @Company_Name) as concatted",
            new { person.Name, Company_Name = person.Company.Name });
```

Edit: No, you can't pass in the object as it is as dapper does a very straight-forward sql-param to object param mapping.

It has to be either of type: `IDynamicParameters` , `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` or an anonymous object where the param values are evaluated based on the name of the sql param literals. See https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/a18dc63c688b5173c5dde8b1243b74e26fa262c4/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs#L2367 on how its implemented.

Comment: That means creating a new object on the fly, to transform the nested object I already had. That sounds like DynamicParameters but with extra steps. Can I not just send the nested object I already had?

Comment: See my edit, you can't pass in nested objects because the value resolution for anonymous types happens based on the t-sql param name (And does not support nesting).

Comment: Hi Alex, 4 years later and your answer is still being helpful. I thought that this was the case but your answer and link confirmed it.